# Как установить обработчик нажатия на ImageViewer?

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать так, как в последнем примере в этой статье(https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer). Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на элемент появилось описание, а при последующем - пропало. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявляешь переменную, которая будет показывать состояние видимости твоего описания

```
boolean visibility = true;
```

создаешь метод, который будет реагировать на нажатие по изображению

```
public void visibilityClickIV(View view) {

    if (visibility==true) {
        visibility = false;
        tvopisanie.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        visibility = true;
        tvopisanie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

где `tvopisanie` - `(TextView)` твоего описания, ставишь в файл разметки в `(ImageView)` свой метод в `onClick`

```
android:onClick="visibilityClickIV"
```